# Get history of changes to A records of DNS FQDN

Tags: dns

E.g. for api.friendlycaptcha, how can I find out the changes in DNS A records for a few weeks (tricky one as it is cloudflare and I assume the results varies depending on geo location of the requestor). Is there any archive service or any other hint that I can look into? Thanks!

Comment: You can try https://securitytrails.com/dns-trails and after a search you will see Historical Data on the left.  May or may not have what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This site worked for me. I needed to find a subdomain's old IP entries. https://suip.biz/?act=domainiphistory